# Matplotlib finance plot_day_summary_ohlc using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use some of these code but actually I need different output

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.finance import plot_day_summary_ohlc, volume_overlay
  from matplotlib import dates

  df = pd.read_csv("try_stock.csv")
  x = df.set_index('Date')
  x['t']=x.index.map(dates.datestr2num)

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,1), (0,3), rowspan=3)

  print (df.index)
  print type(ef['t'])

  plot_day_summary_ohlc(ax1, x[['t','Total TradedAmount','ClosePrice','Max. Price', 'Min. Price','Total Traded Shares','Total Transactions']].values, ticksize=3, colorup=u'k', colordown=u'r')

  df = df.set_index('t')

  volume_overlay(ax2, df['previousClosing'], df['closingPrice'], df['totalShare'], colorup=u'k', colordown=u'r', width=4, alpha=1.0)

  ax1.xaxis_date()
  ax2.xaxis_date()  
  plt.show()
```

Current out is like this:
[Output shouldn't be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmQ95.png)

Output must be like this:
[Output somehow look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs3cT.png)

Comment: i can provide data if needed

Comment: Always provide [example data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/2087463) for pandas questions.